Facing issue matTableExporter using pagination length variable
I'm encountering an issue with matTableExporter server-side pagination in my Angular app. On the initial load, I have 15 records displayed in the table, and I want to export just those records. However, my total dataset contains about 6,000 records. When I click the export button, it triggers a request to fetch all 6,000 records, but only downloads the 15 records currently visible on the page.
I need the export functionality to download only the records currently displayed on the page, without fetching data from other pages
